# Require.js - How to load compiled modules dynamically?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

If I have a **Build Config** like this...

```
({
    appDir: 'app',
    baseUrl: '.',
    dir: 'dist',    
    modules: [
        {
            name: 'main',
        },{
            name: 'modules/example/ExampleController',
            exclude: ['main']
        },{
            name: 'modules/another/AnotherController',
            exclude: ['main']
        },{
            ...
        }
    ]
})
```

...and a **Directory Structure** like this...

```
├── app
│   ├── modules
│   │   ├── example
│   │   ╰── another
│   │       ├── AnotherController.js
│   │       ╰── AnotherView.stache
│   ╰── main.js
├── dist
│   ├── modules
│   │   ├── example_module
│   │   ╰── another_module
│   │       ╰── AnotherController.js
│   ╰── main.js
├── build.js
╰── index.html
```

...and an **index.html** like this...

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script src="lib/requirejs/require.js" data-main="dist/main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

Then the first **dist/main.js** is loaded great, but dynamically loading the **another/AnotherController.js** module will load the non-optimized one from **app**, and not the compiled/optimized one from **dist**, because the build config has a **appDir:'app'**. But changing the **appDir** breaks the build.

*So how am I supposed to load compiled modules dynamically?*

Comment: possible duplicate of [Require.js Build Optimization Configuration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28437563/require-js-build-optimization-configuration)

Comment: @Louis That was my question! I tried to ask a more pointed question this time around.

Comment: "So how am I supposed to load compiled modules dynamically?" The answer on your other question fully answers your question here. Point 2 in particular.

Comment: @Louis It's a workaround, and I would still need to manually update the compiled main module's require config's baseUrl from **app** to **dist/app** If require includes the means to compile multiple modules, there must be a better way.

Comment: You may want to have a look at [require-lazy](https://github.com/nikospara/require-lazy).